# My column is not blank but i'm getting this error: Unknown column '' in 'where clause'

Tags: php, mysql

I know the column npi exists so I'm not sure why i'm getting this error; I've read a few other threads on here but nothing is working for me. In my where clause, i've tried backticks and single quotes but no avail. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

```
 <?php
    include('config.php');
    if (isset($_GET['insurance_id']) ) {
    $insurance_id = (string) $_GET['insurance_id'];
    if (isset($_POST['submitted'])) {
    foreach($_POST AS $key => $value) { $_POST[$key] = mysql_real_escape_string($value); }
    $sql = ("UPDATE `doctor_data` SET `dr_first_name` = '{$_POST['dr_first_name']}', `dr_last_name` = '{$_POST['dr_last_name']}' where npi='$npi'");

    mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    echo (mysql_affected_rows()) ? "Edited Record.<br />" : "Nothing changed. <br />";
    echo "<a href='index.php?id=28&insurance_id=($REQUEST:insurance_id)'>Back To List</a>";
    }
    $row = mysql_fetch_array ( mysql_query("SELECT * from `doctor_data`"));
    ?>

    <form action='' method='POST'>
    <p><b>Doctor:</b><br /><input type='text' name='dr_first_name' value='<?= stripslashes($row['dr_first_name']) ?>' /> <input type='text' name='dr_last_name' value='<?= stripslashes($row['dr_last_name']) ?>' />
    <p><input class="btn btn-success" type='submit' value='Update Record' /><input type='hidden' value='1' name='submitted' />
    </form>
    <? } ?>
```

Additionally, the data is being saved on the form after it's being posted but not into the database and upon pushing the post button I receive the error message posted in the title.

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 3.4.11.1
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
--
-- Host: localhost
-- Generation Time: Feb 15, 2013 at 05:50 PM
-- Server version: 5.5.23
-- PHP Version: 5.2.17

SET SQL_MODE="NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;

--
-- Database: `anag_demo`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `doctor_data`
--

CREATE TABLE `doctor_data` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `npi` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `dr_first_name` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `dr_last_name` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `npi` (`npi`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=17 ;

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

Comment: perhaps try to echo out the query string and run it directly against mysql, this often shines some additional light onto what might be the problem...

Comment: you should really look at using mysqli or pdo instead of old school mysql. That said, you probably need to escape the single quotes wrapping $npi - $sql = ("UPDATE `doctor_data` SET `dr_first_name` = '{$_POST['dr_first_name']}', `dr_last_name` = '{$_POST['dr_last_name']}' where npi=\'$npi\'");

Comment: Can you post the `show create table doctor_data`? FTR, you don't need parens around the update statement, nor do you need backticks around schema references.

Comment: I'll post it Mike, one minute.

Comment: Nevermind the schema, your update string was malformed, I posted a fix.

Comment: Lol, just wanted to make sure you indeed had an npi column.

Comment: hahaha.. all good my friend. ; ]

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$nameFirst = $_POST['dr_first_name'];
$nameLast = $_POST['dr_last_name'];

$sql = "UPDATE doctor_data SET dr_first_name = '$nameFirst', dr_last_name = '$nameLast' where npi = '$npi'";
```

The string is malformed b/c you have a series of single quotes, some meant to indicate string passed to mysql, and others indicating a key for an associative array reference. As mentioned in the comments you should look into [PDO](http://php.net/pdo), and [bindValue](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php).

-- **Update** --

Chances are you have an apostrophe in the last name, which is causing the breakage. You should always **sanitize** vars being passed to mysql to ensure that malicious users don't try to execute nefarious commands. Your using the deprecated mysql api, you should at least shift to [mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or better yet pdo as mentioned above. In any event, try this:

```
$nameFirst = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['dr_first_name']);
$nameLast = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['dr_last_name']);
```

Comment: I'll try that now. Thank you Mike

Comment: Just to be clear, I'm deleting this line: $sql = ("UPDATE `doctor_data` SET `dr_first_name` = '{$_POST['dr_first_name']}', `dr_last_name` = '{$_POST['dr_last_name']}' where npi='$npi'");
and adding your answer above in it's place?

Comment: Didn't work, same error message: Unknown column '' in 'where clause' I truly appreciate the help.

Comment: Please post the value of `$sql`.

Comment: <?php var_dump ($sql); ?> returned null...     =/

Comment: Sorry I didn't see that you were already escaping the data. I guess the bigger issue is why the $sql var is null. You did the `var_dump` right before the `mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());` call?

Comment: at first i didn't, i just added it at the bottom and it returned null, when i added it above the or die it returned nothing.

Comment: Ya at the bottom it would be null unless you submitted the form so the conditional where the `$sql = ...` assignment is executed. I don't get how you make the assignment, then var_dump and it returns nothing the next line?